# What should my index file look like if I move everything else out of public folder?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to take everything except public file(s) out of my ReST API application to an upper-level, which is NOT accessible through browsers. But I'm having problems. I want to know how I should do this. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNxjy.jpg) reflects my current structure.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

None of your current api files will be accessible through browsers,

An even better way to protect your data is to use Webpack and Minify (Compiles and Compresses the JS) this makes the JS that the browser uses completely inaccessible.

Check this out.
Minifying 101: https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/minifying/